# How do I programmatically set a custom field on the Lead/Contact entity to be merged automatically in MS CRM 4 and 5?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have two fields on the Lead and Contact record and I want to set those up so that when duplicate Lead/Contact records are merged or we convert a lead into a contact, those custom fields get merged every time without having to do any extra work. You can set this up manually so I imagine it can also be done programmatically... I just can't seem to find information on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a plugin on the Merge message for the lead or contact entities. There, you'll have access to the primary and secondary records, and you can move fields to the primary as you need to.

UPDATE: Per your comment, there's an entity called 'attributemap' that can be used to retrieve the mappings ('entitymap' is the parent entity if you need to retrieve the maps for only a certain set of entities). You can give creating one of these a try programmatically, not sure if the API will let you.

Comment: We tend to try to stay away from plugins. Isn't there any way to pull and edit the contact_originating_lead mappings? That's how you would set it up manually.